# Black Screen/Video Drivers Crashing on Login

Tags: 14.04, drivers, login, intel, crash

I have a new laptop which I have been running Ubuntu on for a few days without any problems. Now when I turn on the computer it gets to the login screen, and if I try to log into my profile there's a visual glitch that looks like the video driver crashing, and the screen goes black. Logging into a guest account works fine.

Edit: Forgot to mention, the login screen also has this weird visual glitch which I took a picture of [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV0uL.jpg)

Info in case any of this is needed:

Ubuntu Version 14.04.1 LTS

Dell Inspiron 3531

Intel Celeron N2830

Intel HD Graphics